# Getting incorrect index number when scrolling through UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, indexpath

I'm building a flashcard app where you select a deck of cards from one collection view and depending on the cell being displayed which has a deck title image, you are presented with a particular deck in another collection view.

I have a viewController which returns 10 cells as decks to be selected and a viewController for the card viewer with a cell count dependent on the deck to be returned. Each of these viewControllers have cell classes. I'm having trouble figuring out a way to return the correct cards and cell count depending on the deck I've selected.

What I've tried to do is to tell it to return a particular string depending on the indexPath.item and use that as the image name. This works except that the indexPath.item isn't returning as I expected and I get the wrong deck of cards so it seems that I'm misunderstanding the way the indexPath.item is determined and I cannot come up with a working solution to return the correct deck.

SEE IMAGE -
[Image of code and printed results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhIt1.png)
You'll see the index numbers printed in an odd fashion after cells have been scrolled through.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! HomeViewCell

    collectionView.bounces = false

    let imageNumber = indexPath.item

    getNumber(imageNumber: imageNumber)
    let image = collectionImageArray[imageNumber].withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    cell.collectionImage.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    cell.collectionImage.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCollectionTap), for: .touchUpInside)

    print(imageNumber)

    return cell
}
```

As I scroll down to the second cell, the index number is jumping from 0 to 2 and continues 3, 4, 5... If I scroll up from index 4 to 3, it prints that I'm jumping from 3 to 0.

Comment: `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` will be called at any time in any order when iOS decides it needed, it's unpredictable. What's the problem with the current output shown in the image?

Comment: The problem is that I scroll down to the second cell and it gives me index 2 instead of 1. When I start the app it starts at index 0 as expected but jumps to 2 when scrolled once but comtinues in succession 3, 4, 5... as I continue to scroll down.

Comment: That does not explain if it really is a problem. Why _the number jumps to 2_ is problematic ? Why do you expect the numbers to be shown in order?

Comment: Because I expect that the index number represents which cell I'm viewing. Am I misunderstanding the index? When I'm viewing the second cell for example, my code would say this is index number 1 so display this deck of cards when clicked. But I get index 2 instead of one. Index 2 would be the third cell correct?

Comment: _Because I expect that the index number represents which cell I'm viewing. Am I misunderstanding the index?_ Yes, you are misunderstanding. The index number represents the cell which iOS wants to get, not the index you are viewing.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. If you could give me a better idea as to how the index that iOS wants is determined, I appreciate it. And if you have an idea on how I can achieve what I'm trying to do another way, I'm all ears. Thank you!!!

Comment: Please update your question and clarify what you are trying to do. Currently, you are just saying that the printed index is not in order. Better try to explain what you are trying to do. Forget the printed index and describe what is the difficulty about achieving your goal.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question.

Comment: @CodeHurts I am facing the same problem, how did you solve your problem?